# Table improvement

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, multirow

I have made a table and I would like to have feedback and possible improvement from you (I am beginner in table uses).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,newtxmath} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[bt]
\caption{Scenario results}\label{tab4}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} c *{10}{Z} @{}}
\toprule
 &  \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly 2} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly 3} & Anomaly anticipation\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}\cmidrule(l){8-10}\cmidrule(l){11-11}
 Scenario & Detection & Propagation on system variables & Pump impact rates & Detection & Propagation on system variables & Pump impact rates & Detection & Propagation on system variables & Pump impact rates & $\Delta t$\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
%Scenario 1
\multirow{2}{*}{1} & $ed_{coh}$=$true$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$s_{2}$$\rightarrow$$f_{2}$$\rightarrow$$l_{1}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PU1(65.6\%)\\ PU2(65.6\%)\end{tabular}}& $ed_{coh}$=$true$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$s_{1}$$\rightarrow$$f_{1}$$\rightarrow$$l_{1}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PU1(65.6\%)\\ PU2(65.6\%)\end{tabular}} & $cd_{err}$=$true$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$l_{1}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PU1(68.8\%) \\ T1(68.8\%)\end{tabular}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{22,6h}} \\
& t=57h & & & t=79h & & & t=79,6h \\
\addlinespace
%Scenario 2
\multirow{2}{*}{2}  & $cd_{err}$=$true$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$l_{7}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PU10(68.8\%)\\ PU11(68.8\%)\end{tabular}}& n/a & \multirow{2}{*}{n/a} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}n/a\\n/a\end{tabular}} & n/a & \multirow{2}{*}{n/a} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}n/a\\ n/a\end{tabular}}& \multirow{2}{*}{n/a}  \\
& t=30h & & & n/a & & & n/a \\
\addlinespace
%Scenario 3
\multirow{2}{*}{3}  & $ed_{coh}$=$true$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$s_{4}$$\rightarrow$$f_{4}$$\rightarrow$$l_{3}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PU4(65.6\%)\\PU5(65.6\%)\end{tabular}}& $ed_{coh}$=$true$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$s_{5}$$\rightarrow$$f_{5}$$\rightarrow$$l_{3}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PU4(65.6\%)\\PU5(65.6\%)\end{tabular}} & $cd_{err}$=$true$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$l_{3}$} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PU4(68.8\%)\\PU5(68.8\%)\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{9,8h}} \\
& t=3,9h & & & t=11,3h & & & t=13,7h \\
\addlinespace
%Scenario 4
\multirow{2}{*}{4}  & n/a & \multirow{2}{*}{n/a} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}n/a\end{tabular}}& n/a & \multirow{2}{*}{n/a} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}n/a\end{tabular}} & n/a & \multirow{2}{*}{n/a} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}n/a\end{tabular}} 
& \multirow{2}{*}{n/a} \\
& n/a & & & n/a & & & n/a \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Maybe it's would be better to center the text in the first and second row ?

Thanks for your help.

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Personally, I would not vertically center the column headers but use abbreviations to shorten them. This might come in handy to reduce the amount of blank "wasted"  space, especially since the column headers in the second row repeat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't use `\multirow` under any circumstance, but perhaps I can understand it in this case.

I properly segregated math and let TeX do the intercolumn space computations; if you notice, I split the PIR column into two, for better alignment.

Moreover, `siunitx` is used throughout to ensure consistent usage of the decimal marker. If you remove `output-decimal-marker={,}`, you'll get a decimal point everywhere (independently on input).

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{detect-all,output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[bt]
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{#1}}
%\newcommand{\mr}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\edcoh}{\mathrm{ed}_{\mathrm{coh}}}
\newcommand{\cderr}{\mathrm{cd}_{\mathrm{err}}}
\newcommand{\true}{\mathrm{true}}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\caption{Scenario results}\label{tab4}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  *{3}{ c c l @{\extracolsep{0pt}\ } r @{\extracolsep{\fill}} }
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
Scenario &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Anomaly 1} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Anomaly 2} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Anomaly 3} &
AA \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
\cmidrule{6-9}
\cmidrule{10-13}
\cmidrule{14-14}
& Detection & PSV & \mc{PIR}
& Detection & PSV & \mc{PIR}
& Detection & PSV & \mc{PIR}
& $\Delta t$ \\
\midrule
\addlinespace
%Scenario 1
\mr{1} & $\edcoh=\true$ & \mr{$s_{2}\to f_{2}\to l_{1}$} & PU1 & (\num{65.6}\%)
       & $\edcoh=\true$ & \mr{$s_{1}\to f_{1}\to l_{1}$} & PU1 & (\num{65.6}\%)
       & $\cderr=\true$ & \mr{$l_{1}$}                   & PU1 & (\num{68.8}\%) 
       & \mr{\bfseries\SI{22,6}{\hour}} \\
       & $t=\SI{57}{\hour}$   & & PU2 & (\num{65.6}\%)
       & $t=\SI{79}{\hour}$   & & PU2 & (\num{65.6}\%)
       & $t=\SI{79,6}{\hour}$ & & T1 & (\num{68.8}\%) \\
\addlinespace
%Scenario 2
\mr{2} & $\cderr=\true$ & \mr{$l_{7}$} & PU10 & (\num{68.8}\%)
       & n/a            & \mr{n/a}     & \mc{n/a}
       & n/a            & \mr{n/a}     & \mc{n/a} & \mr{n/a}  \\

       & $t=\SI{30}{\hour}$ & & PU11 & (\num{68.8}\%) & n/a & & \mc{n/a} & n/a & & \mc{n/a} \\
\addlinespace
%Scenario 3
\mr{3} & $\edcoh=\true$ & \mr{$s_{4}\to f_{4}\to l_{3}$} & PU4 & (\num{65.6}\%)
       & $\edcoh=\true$ & \mr{$s_{5}\to f_{5}\to l_{3}$} & PU4 & (\num{65.6}\%)
       & $\cderr=\true$ & \mr{$l_{3}$}                   & PU4 & (\num{68.8}\%)
       & \mr{\bfseries\SI{9,8}{\hour}} \\
       & $t=\SI{3,9}{\hour}$  & & PU5 & (\num{65.6}\%)
       & $t=\SI{11,3}{\hour}$ & & PU5 & (\num{65.6}\%)
       & $t=\SI{13,7}{\hour}$ & & PU5 & (\num{68.8}\%) \\
\addlinespace
%Scenario 4
\mr{4} & n/a & \mr{n/a} & \mc{\mr{n/a}} 
       & n/a & \mr{n/a} & \mc{\mr{n/a}}
       & n/a & \mr{n/a} & \mc{\mr{n/a}}
       & \mr{n/a} \\
       & n/a & & & & n/a & & & & n/a \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{14}{l}{PSV: Propagation on system variables; PIR: Pump impact rates;
  AA: Anomaly anticipation}
\end{tabular*}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The temporary commands defined in the `table*` environment aren't only an abbreviation. If I change the definition of `\mr` into

```
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{#1}
```

the output becomes

[image]

which confirms my opinion that every table using `\multirow` can be improved by not removing it. `;-)`

Comment: I just have noticed a thing on the table, why "Scenario" is not centered as the following number ? Whereas the column is defined as a c type. Thanks

Comment: @nicope13 I see it centered.

Comment: Yes it's my bad, with the blank space at the right I thought it was not

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly different approach building upon `siunitx` for the numbers with units less `\multiow` commands, no nested tabulars and `tabular*` instead of `tabularx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs,newtxmath} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[detect-weight]{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[bt]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{Scenario results}\label{tab4}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c *{3}{ccl}c}
\toprule
 &  \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly 2} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anomaly 3} & Anticipation\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}\cmidrule(l){8-10}\cmidrule(l){11-11}
 Scenario & Detection & PSV & \makecell{PIR} & Detection & PSV & \makecell{PIR} & Detection & PSV & \makecell{PIR} & $\Delta t$\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
%Scenario 1
\multirow{2}{*}{1} 
& $ed_{coh}=\text{true}$ 
& \multirow{2}{*}{$s_{2} \rightarrow f_{2} \rightarrow l_{1}$} 
& PU1 (65.6\%)
& $ed_{coh}=\text{true}$ 
& \multirow{2}{*}{$s_{1} \rightarrow f_{1}\rightarrow l_{1}$} 
& PU1 (65.6\%)
& $cd_{err}=\text{true}$ 
& \multirow{2}{*}{$l_{1}$} 
& PU1 (68.8\%)
& \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries\SI{22,6}{\hour}} \\

& t = \SI{57}{\hour} 
& 
& PU2 (65.6\%)
& t = \SI{79}{\hour} 
& 
& PU2 (65.6\%)
& t = \SI{79,6}{\hour} 
&
& T1 (68.8\%)\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{11}{l}{PSV = Propagation on system variables; PIR =  Pump impact rates}
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @leandriis feeedback I modified the table with abbreviations and it's more readable.

[image]

Comment: It will be even better if you clarify the meaning of the abbreviations as notes at the end of the table.